# How to solve OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

There seems to be a problem when I use smtplib. It works fine when I try this at home, on laptop.It fails when I try this with Raspberry, at university.
The problem seems to be with university proxy, which blocks smtplib.

If this is the case, how to fix this problem?
If not, what else could be the reason for this?

```
import smtplib 

gmailaddress = 'probnimejl@exapmple.com'
gmailpassword = 'password'
mailto = 'probnimejl@example.com'
msg = str(input("What is your message? \n "))

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.com' , 587)
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.login(gmailaddress , gmailpassword)
mailServer.sendmail(gmailaddress, mailto , msg)
print(" \n Sent!")
mailServer.quit()
```

When I run this code I get following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.com' , 587)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Comment: I hope you haven't posted you real e-mail and password for the entire Internet to see. If so, you should change your password ASAP.

Comment: What proxy? Apparently it blocks these protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Most large organizations such as a university with an IT staff that is trained and knowledgeable will have policies in place about the use of information technology resources.

These policies are enforced through a variety of measures such as firewall settings to block particular hosts or particular ports, resource limits (maximum disk space allotments, maximum network bandwidth allowed before throttling, etc.), what protocols are allowed to be used, and what versions of software may be used.

A simple test is to use an application such as `telnet` to attempt to create a network connection between your host, the Raspberry Pi, and the host outside of the university network. For example `telnet smtp.example.com 587` to see if that works.

You may be running into a university firewall setting which is blocking the use of port 587. Or you may be running into a problem that the university network doesn't recognize your Raspberry Pi and refuses to allow it to use the network.

Without knowing the specific reason for the failure, it's hard to say however I think the best course of action is to talk with the university IT staff to find out what are the university policies about what you are trying to do.

After that conversation, you will be able to determine what your options are.

One workaround is to have the Raspberry Pi outside of the university network and access it remotely.